# how to extract all frame form video using opencv java?

Tags: java, opencv

I have a project video encoding and as library I use ***openCV + Netbean***, I want to extract all the frames before I process it.
anyone can help give me explain or source code Java OpenCV.

```
VideoCapture v=new VideoCapture("file.avi");
ArrayList<BufferedImage> frames=new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
Buffered frame=new BufferedImage();
Mat nmat=new Mat();
boolean hasNext = true;
while(hasNext){
      hasNext = v.read(nmat);
      frame=v.grab();
      frames.add(frame);
}
```

Comment: v.read will fill the Mat object. What do you expect v.grab should do? What is BufferedImage? Sorry I only know openCV c++ syntax. Imho after v.read you should buffer nmat

Comment: thanks, solved problem, i will to try manipulation the bufferedImage, Yesterday i think so, but i was wrong.